# How to pause Selenium execution when progress bar is shown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I have a Angular SPA application which I would like to automate. When this progress bar is shown:

```
<div _ngcontent-cln-c1="" class="ngx-loading-text center-center" style="top: calc(50% + 60px + 5px); color: white;">Loading...</div>
```

I would like to pause globally the execution of Java code. Is it possible to pause Selenium somehow if this div is visible?

Comment: might want to try with WebDriverEventListeners: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html

Comment: Would you please show me how to configure it globally to wait for the `Loading...` text and pause the execution?

Comment: configure one of the options/answers below to run with a webdrivereventlistener (or 2?) Depends on when this might appear.  They are fairly new so I don't really know how supported they are and whether they might meet your needs.  You might also build them into a sort of "driveractions" class to run before any driver action.  Build the architecture to suit your needs.  Be sure to consider the time it takes for the loading... element to load/appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### invisibilityOf()

[**`invisibilityOf(WebElement element)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) is defined as:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> invisibilityOf(WebElement element)

An expectation for checking the element to be invisible
```

Here the expectation is that, the element must be **present** as well as **visible** as a pre-condition and the method will wait for the element to be **invisible**. At this point it is worth to mention that as the argument is of type *WebElement*, `findElement(By by)` have to successfully locate the element as a pre-condition. Hence `NoSuchElementException` can't be **ignored**.

---

### invisibilityOfElementLocated()

[**`invisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) is defined as:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> invisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)

An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.
```

Here the expectation is clearly either the element is already **invisible** or **not present** in the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). In this case the primary mission is the **absence** of the element which may occur even before the *ExpectedCondition* is invoked or during the *timespan* while the *ExpectedCondition* is active. So here we need to ignore `NoSuchElementException` as a mandatory measure.

---

### This usecase

To pause the execution of your program you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `invisibilityOf()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]"))));
  ```
- Using `invisibilityOfElementLocated()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

you can use webdriver wait for this :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);


wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(loadingelement)));
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);


wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf​(loadingelement)));
```

**The above will wait till the loading elment is invisibile or stale ( means modified or removed)**

**You can also use:**

```
List<WebElement> elementName = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"ngx-loading-text center-center\"]"));

while(elementlist.size()){
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  elementName = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"ngx-loading-text center-center\"]"));
}
```

The above code will check findelements list  is empty else wai 1 second and then try to find again and the loop continues till size is 0